# Time Series Graph DB

Tags: neo4j

Anybody know of any Graph DB's that support time series data?

Ideally we're looking for one that will scale well, and ideally use Cassandra or HBase as their persistent store.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? Best practice would be to store the dependency graph (in other words, the "Model" of the time series data) in a graphdb, but the actual time series in something more suited to that. Eg a KV store or a log-specific tool like Splunk...

See the KNMI (Dutch Weather Service) example for a case study: http://vimeopro.com/neo4j/graphconnect-europe-2015/video/128351859

Cheers!

Rik

Comment: Thank you for sharing the video. It seems they talk about state changes. My interpretation of this is that the state changes are loaded into Neo4j with a model of the relationships between those data points for analysis. This sounds like an interesting concept. However, if we want to look at the data over time, for example temperature over course of a month - how would this be achieved? Especially if we want to use the relationship model in Neo4j.

Comment: I think you would have to have an application that talks to 2 different datastores. Neo4j for the rels/dependencies, and the KV store (or whatever aggregate store you use) for the actual time series filtering/aggregation.

Comment: Because sometimes you ask questions like "show me the nodes and relationships that occurred between date/time and date/time", or "show me anything that happened, related to one specific node I'm interested in between date/time and date/time"

Answer (score 9):

One convenient way of doing that is to build a tree structure, with a common root, years as children, months as children of each year and down to the desired granularity.
At the end you attach the events nodes as leaf to this tree, and that give you the possibility to make many types of queries, from single point in time, to ranges, and also reverse, from the event to the timestamp...

[Here is an example of this concept and an implementation within Neo4j](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2014/08/20/graphaware-neo4j-timetree.html)